# Disable sailjs .tmp/public grunt process for dev

Tags: sails.js

**The problem**: Sail.js is using a Gruntfile with watch to constantly generate and move assets to a .tmp/public file for public consumption.  Every time I make a change, this happens.  Over and Over and Over again.... Its killing my mac.  Not only does it spam error

```
error: Grunt :: 2014-01-24 16:29 node[4935] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21)

error: Grunt :: 2014-01-24 16:29 node[4935] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21)

error: Grunt :: 2014-01-24 16:29 node[4935] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21)

error: Grunt :: 2014-01-24 16:29 node[4935] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamStart: register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-21)
```

(x10000)

But it is causing my IDE (Webstorm) to keep reindexing the files, over and over again.

**The Question**: Is there any config/setting/way to disable this and just have the assets be hosted from the assets folder directly.  I understand the need for the .tmp/public and what it is doing, its just I don't have that need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The location of your public folder is configurable as `sails.config.paths.public`.  So you can set it in your `config/local.js` like:

```
module.exports = {

   paths: {
     public: __dirname+'/../assets' // or wherever
   },

   ...etc...

}
```

You can also make a new config file like `config/paths.js` and set it in there if you want to check the configuration in with the rest of your project.

As far as Grunt goes, the simplest solution is to just remove/rename `Gruntfile.js`.  Grunt will throw an error when Sails lifts, but no further harm will come of it.

Comment: You can also disable the Grunt-hook to remove the annoying message when you lift :) Just add `"hooks": { "grunt": false }` to the `.sailsrc`-file.

Answer (score 3):

For webstorm, you can mark the .tmp directory as Excluded. This will hide the the dir from the IDE, but it will also prevent it from looking at it.